# newbie: how to get single value from {:country_code=>"FR", :country_code1=>"FRE", :country_name=>"France", :region=>"11", :city=>"Paris"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

How to get single value from {:country_code=>"FR", :country_code1=>"FRE", :country_name=>"France", :region=>"11", :city=>"Paris"} ?

I want to get the value of :city
nothing works what I try :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is a [hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html).

```
hash = {:country_code=>"FR", :country_code1=>"FRE", :country_name=>"France", :region=>"11", :city=>"Paris"}

puts hash[:city]
>> "Paris"
```

Comment: thx I think I confused it with an array :S then when I used hash to get it used the wrong syntax.